# Accessing a UIViewController using storyboardID without instantiating it

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Is there any way to access a `UIViewController` without using the function `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String)`. I have to call the function `tableView.ReloadData()` from within another `UIViewController` which I have transitioned to using a show segue and I therefore do not want to instantiate the initial `UIViewController` again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access through `UINavigationController` stack. Let say if it is one controller before, you can access it using the total viewcontrollers (in stack) minus 2

```
let previousController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[(self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count)! - 2] as! YourViewController
```

more simplified

```
let controllerIndex = (self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count)! - 2
let previousController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[controllerIndex] as! YourViewController
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer worked! The only problem is that hardcoding the value 2 as the index is not too elegant. If for example another intermediate `UIViewController` was added you would have to update the value to 3. But it is good enough for my implementation as it is to be used on a "developer" view :) Cheers!

Comment: Great, just take note you could loop through the viewcontrollers and find the matched